# Calling a module in python to process the same file. It works in one scenario, but not in the other, and I can't figure out what's different

Tags: python, file-io

[image]

As you can see from the image above,I call the `txt_to_csv_space_split_version()` module in the script on the top left and in the script on the bottom right. On the top left, the text file isn't read for some reason (output on top right), but in the bottom right, it is (output on bottom left).

I hope that this makes sense-please feel free to ask for clarification!
Many thanks!!

Edit: the green circles point to where the module gets called in each of the scripts. The green rectangle highlights the module definition. The red circles show that the same text file is being read (by the same module) in both scripts.
And yet, somehow, the module doesn't seem to be working correctly for the script in the top left.

Comment: Sorry! They still look ok to me when I zoom my browser in...

Comment: @Levon: Right-click the image, click 'Open image in a new tab' to see at full size. However, even at full size, I don't understand what's going on with all the arrows and circles all over the place.

Comment: Ok, I hopefully explained it a little better in the edit. My bad.

Comment: I can't see any difference between the two scripts. Maybe the file you're reading is getting truncated somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahaha! I found it! I forgot output_file.close() before passing it along to the module! I don't quite understand why that made it work, but it did! Thanks so much @Amr for putting me on the right path with your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You're opening your file in the upper left  script with 'w' mode, this will wipe it's contents out.

```
output_file=open("/Users/markfisher/Desktop/"+filenames[index]+'_output.txt','w')
```

Then you call a function which opens that file to read it's contents:

```
name_to_be_split="/Users/markfisher/Desktop/"+filenames[index]+'_output.txt'
#print something
transpose.txt_to_csv_space_split_version(name_to_be_split)
```

`index` doesn't change during the script, so the file name is the same.

at this point the file contents are already wiped out, so there's nothing to read.
At least that's what I could gather from the multiple stuff you put in that picture :)